# Error installing Host Only Adapter from Virtual Box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, adapter

I always get an error while trying to install the Host only Adapter in Virtual box, it doesn't matter if I try it with Powershell, Vagrant or VirtualBox itself.

The Error Message is:
[Error from VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHGzN.png)
Versions:
Im running Windows 10 Creators Update.
The VirtualBox Versions I tried are 5.2.0, 5.1.30, 5.1.28, 5.1.26
The Vagrant version is 2.0.1

I also tried as Admin, deactivate Antivirus and Firewall, restart PC, and installing the VirtualBox Extension Pack.

Some people say its because of the Win10 Creators Update, can someone confirm that?

Comment: can confirm, it's the creators update. Hopefully there's a fix soon

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and updating Virtualbox to Version 5.1.30 r118389 (Qt5.6.2) worked for me.

I have Vagrant 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it
reinstalled Windows 10 now without the Creators update and it works.